# Как заполнить список в python файлами?

Tags: python, файлы

Я сейчас перед собой поставил одну из задач: составить список из имён файлов, которые будут сохраняться в отдельной папке. Я как понимаю, нужен модуль glob, чтобы привязать путь для файлов к списку. Я написал код, но список мне на выводе приходит пустой.

Выглядит всё вот так:

```
import glob

f1 = open('1.txt', 'w+')
f1.write("Яблоко")
f1.close()

f2 = open('2.txt', 'w+')
f2.write("Груша")
f2.close()

f3 = open('3.txt', 'w+')
f3.write("Слива")
f3.close()

textlist = glob.glob('/texts/*')
print(textlist)
```

Что тут может быть не так? И каким способом я могу добиться вышеописанной цели?

Answer (score 0):

Вы создаёте/пишете файлы в текущем каталоге, а потом берёте список файлов из каталога `/texts/`. Чтобы всё работало, открывайте файлы с указанием полного каталога, т.е., например:

```
open('/texts/1.txt', 'w+')
```